# What are the words to express sobbing and crying sound?

Tags: onomatopoeia, sounds

Google doesn't help much.

What are the sounds (written in words) that people usually use to express their crying/sobbing emotions such as in chat, social network?

For example if I say, "I am sad [sobbing]", this is ok but I want to replace it with sound to express more emotion.

In my own language "sig sig" would be the sound for sobbing but I guess if I wrote "sig sig", English speaker friends wouldn't understand me.

Comment: by the way `onomatopoeia` is the word you're looking for for words the represent the an actual sounds (eg. 'Boom!' 'Bang!' 'Clunk!' 'Clack!') Try attaching that to your google searches.

Comment: I'm not aware of any terms in English that express sobbing/crying using onomatopoeia.  (Except perhaps "waah".)

Comment: Two words that you may like are 'weeping' and 'wailing' for sobbing and crying respectively.

Comment: You can use for eg. "Sniff,sniff,you wouldn't understand"
If you want to use it in a sentence

Answer (score 5):

For crying there is "Waa" or "Waah", which is usually to represent a babies cry (ie. a howling cry, not sobbing).

eg.

> Waaaa! I dropped my phone and broke the screen!
>
> Waa waa, cry me a river.

Answer (score 5):

**Boohoo**

> used to represent the sound of someone crying noisily.

For example, "Boohoo! I just lost my phone."

**Blubber** (informal)

> cry noisily and uncontrollably; sob.

For example, "He was blubbering like a kid"

**Bawl**

> to cry out loudly and unrestrainedly.

**Caterwaul**

> to make a harsh cry (like a cat in heat).

Source: Oxford Dictionaries

[**Sniff sniff**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Sniff-%20Sniff)

> This in fact is not a spoken word so much as a sound. It is the same sound made when someone is sniffing their nose as they are crying or trying to stop crying. The recovery sniffs is the sound you are mocking.
>
> It is a sarcastic way to show someone you feel no pity for their situation.

[**Sob sob**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=sob%20sob)

> A saying used when feeling unhappy or sad via text or email.

[**And then there are other ways to cry...**](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/20-ways-to-cry/)

Answer (score 2):

In English, the sound of crying is often given as "boo hoo." It's often used sarcastically as well to floccinaucinihilipilificate a reported problem (e.g. "You lost a quarter? Well boo hoo for you.") but it is the onomatopoeia in English for crying aloud.

Comment: Holy cow that's an awesome word I'd never heard of.

Comment: I have waited *years* for the chance to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Boohoo

Definition of boohoo in English:
exclamation

Used to represent the sound of someone crying noisily.

‘boohoo, nobody loves me!’

([Ref](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/boohoo))

PS: An Onomatopoeia Dictionary can give you some more possibilities.